# What is the difference between core and vendor directories in PyroCMS?

Tags: pyrocms

According to PyroCMS [documentation](https://pyrocms.com/documentation/pyrocms/3.4/structure/the-core-directory), the `core` directory **contains any addon required by your composer.json file**, while the `vendor` directory **contains your Composer dependencies**.

Unless I'm missing something obvious, these two mean one and the same thing. Is there an explanation?

Answer (score 1):

Addons are `streams-addon` type composer packages but we isolate them in their own directory to make it easier to register/boot our addons layer.

Addons (core or otherwise) contribute the core functionality to PyroCMS (pages, posts, content blocks) whereas vendor packages are there typically for underlying support (laravel, twig, etc).

Answer (score 0):

According to the source code of the streams-composer plugin, which is managing that behavior, https://github.com/anomalylabs/streams-composer-plugin/blob/master/src/Installer/AddonInstaller.php

We can see that only

```
/**
 * Addon types
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $types = [
    'distribution',
    'field_type',
    'extension',
    'module',
    'plugin',
    'block',
    'theme',
];
```

https://github.com/anomalylabs/streams-composer-plugin/blob/master/src/Installer/AddonInstaller.php#L15-L28 types of packages will be placed under `core` folder.

UPD: Ah, the package should be a `streams-addon`.